# What's wrong with my UPDATE CASE query?

Tags: mysql

My Mysql is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1`, I have many UPDATE, like

```
update player set playorder = 1 where id = 4;
update player set playorder = 2 where id = 5;
update player set playorder = 3 where id = 1;
....
```

i put them into one UPDATE

```
update player set playorder = (CASE
 when id = 4 then 1 
 when id = 5 then 2 
 when id = 1 then 3 END);
```

I found  id=5 playorder is 1, I can't figure out what's the problem. Thanks for any help.

The first sentence of my question is what version about MySQL on my box. So it's better if all experiment on `SQL fiddle` is on version 5.1.xx. When i update MySQL to 5.5.xx on my box, The odd result disappeared. So I think it's the bug that makes `UPDATE CASE` sentence fails.I can not build schema on version 5.1.xx on site SQL fiddle.I hope someone can do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL update CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else)

Comment: Syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: There is no any problem in query it working fine check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73b54/1

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html):

> The first version returns the result where `value=compare_value`. The
>   second version returns the result for the first condition that is
>   true. If there was no matching result value, the result after `ELSE`
>   is returned, or `NULL` if there is no `ELSE` part.

Try this

```
 Update player 
   Set playorder = Case When id = 4 Then 1 
                        When id = 5 Then 2 
                        When id = 1 Then 3 
                   Else Null 
                   END
```

Comment: playorder is null where id is 1, playorder is null where id is 4, and playorder is 1    where id is 5.

Comment: @Ron Check your Column (Id) values well because it's working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2226/1)

Comment: @Ron If id column is `Varchar` field then check ant trailing or leading space around the valeues

Comment: Maybe it's bug of version 5.1.69. fiddle's mysql is 5.5.32.

Comment: @Kumar  could you build schema on 5.1.61? From my ip, building is very slow.