# MySQL/SQL query with errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query below, with quite a few errors in.

Does anyone know MySQL/SQL good enough to fix the errors?

```
UPDATE shopproducts AS wesp
JOIN currencies AS wec
JOIN shopcategories AS wesc
JOIN shops AS wes
IF(wesc.adelivery = 1)
    SET wesp.totalprice = ROUND(wesp.price / 100 * wec.value, 0) + wes.adelivery
ELSE IF(wesc.bdelivery = 1)
    SET wesp.totalprice = ROUND(wesp.price / 100 * wec.value, 0) + wes.bdelivery
ELSE
    IF(wesp.price <= wes.freedelivery)
        SET wesp.totalprice = ROUND(wesp.price / 100 * wec.value, 0)
    ELSE
        SET wesp.totalprice = ROUND(wesp.price / 100 * wec.value, 0) + wes.stddelivery
WHERE wesp.currency = wec.name
AND wesp.sortcategory = wesc.category
AND wesp.shop = wes.name
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: And what did **you** do to fix errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way,

```
UPDATE shopproducts AS wesp
JOIN currencies AS wec
JOIN shopcategories AS wesc
JOIN shops AS wes
SET wesp.totalprice = case when (wesc.adelivery = 1) then ROUND(wesp.price / 100 * wec.value, 0) + wes.adelivery .....(like this way all the when) end  

WHERE wesp.currency = wec.name
AND wesp.sortcategory = wesc.category
AND wesp.shop = wes.name
```

Comment: This also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else