# How to update two rows by one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
// Answers
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| id |  answer | accepted-answer | question_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1  | answer1 | null            | 1           |
| 2  | answer2 | 1               | 1           |
| 3  | answer3 | null            | 1           |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now I'm trying to change `accepted-answer`. I want this **output:**

```
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| id |  answer | accepted-answer | question_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1  | answer1 | null            | 1           |
| 2  | answer2 | null            | 1           |
| 3  | answer3 | 1               | 1           |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Note:** I just have the new id *(the id of new accepted answer, not old one)* which is `$id=3` in the example above. I also have `question_id` which is `$question_id=1` in the example above.

---

I can do that by two separated queries like these:

```
UPDATE Answers SET accepted_answer = null WHERE question_id = :question_id;
```

And

```
UPDATE Answers SET accepted_answer = 1 WHERE id = :id;
```

---

Now I want to know, can I do that in the same time and in one query?

Comment: How about `...SET accepted_answer = CASE WHEN question_id ... THEN... WHEN... THEN END`

Comment: Control flow is your friend here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else

Comment: @Strawberry Seems good. thank you ...

Comment: One statement here is probably not more efficient than two.  Add conditions and accepted_answer is not null, and accepted_answer <> 1

Comment: Keep the `WHERE` from the first query, and change the `SET` to `SET accepted_answer = IF(id <> :id, NULL, 1)`