# mySql Update Cases Not Working Properly

Tags: mysql

In the query below only first Two cases are working why

```
UPDATE `FundCategory` SET `fundCategoryValue` = 
    CASE 
    WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '7' THEN fundCategoryValue + 700 
    WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '5' THEN fundCategoryValue - 700 
    WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '5' THEN fundCategoryValue + 700 
    WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '7' THEN fundCategoryValue - 700 

    ELSE `fundCategoryValue` 
    END
    WHERE `fundCategoryId` IN('7','5','5','7')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else)

Comment: because 3 and 4 are identical to 1 and 2???

Comment: it will not go for next two condition  WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '5' THEN fundCategoryValue + 700 
    WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '7' THEN fundCategoryValue - 700 . it always fulfill first two condition

Answer (score 2):

The conditions repeate after the first two... and the case statement stops when it found a working condition... so the last two can not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same condition repeated twice:

```
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '7' THEN fundCategoryValue + 700 
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '5' THEN fundCategoryValue - 700 
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '5' THEN fundCategoryValue + 700 
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '7' THEN fundCategoryValue - 700
```