# mysql if condition is met

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using MySQL (phpmyadmin) for my database. I want to change the value in a field depending on another's field info.

My table would be "info" and my column1 `store_number`, column2 `store_name` and column3 `state`, so if in field `store_name` there is a character string like `Store number 3`, then change column1 value to `3`.

I tried

```
UPDATE info
IF store_name LIKE "%store number 3 %"
SET store_number = '3'
WHERE state LIKE "%california%"
```

I want to change the store number in all stores in california depending in the store name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with your `WHERE` clause already. You could move your conditional logic to be part of it to get:

```
UPDATE info
SET store_number='3'
WHERE state LIKE '%california%' AND 
  store_name LIKE '%store number 3%'
```

Comment: Thanks my man, i was wondering if i want to change the store number using diferent conditions, can i use like this:   UPDATE info
SET store_number ='3' 
(CASE
WHEN (store_name LIKE "%store number 3 %") THEN '3'
WHEN (store_name LIKE "%store number 4%") THEN '4'
END)
WHERE state LIKE "%california%"

Comment: @Therealguma You can definitely incorporate `CASE` in an update statement. You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else) for an example :)

Comment: Dude, one last thing... let's say i want it to show store name and store number from more than one state... let's say:  `code` SELECT store_number, store_name  FROM info WHERE state ='california' (but here i also need another state, multiple states in the condition WHERE... ) tried WHERE state='california','nevada' did not work.

Comment: You can use `OR`: `... WHERE state='california' OR state='nevada'`.

Comment: Thanks man, i use LIKE to get more results (california1, california2, etc) It does not work when i use 'code' WHERE state LIKE "%california%" OR  "%nevada%", it only displays "%california%" results...

Comment: I just firured it out man, i used 'code' WHERE state LIKE "%california%" OR state LIKE "%nevada%"

Comment: Thank you a lot for all your help!!