# MySQL two alternatives in updating

Tags: mysql

I have a field `visible`. I want to change this value based on the `visible` current value, then update it to the new value.

E.g.

> If visible == 0 change to 1
>
> If visible == 1 change to 0

Comment: Yes you can use either `IF()` function, or `CASE WHEN` statement(s). Refer [Control Flow Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL update CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case when

```
update table set visible=case when visible=0 then 1 when visible=1 then 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

This way should work

```
UPDATE table SET visible = IF(visible = 0, 1, 0) ...
```