# MySQL complicated CASE statement in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get rid of negative values and zero. I took this question as a basis [MySQL update CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else) and tried to compose my request

my query:

```
UPDATE cart
SET cart_count = CASE
 WHEN cart_count >= 2 THEN cart_count = cart_count - 1
 ELSE cart_count = 1
 END
WHERE cart_id = 20 AND cart_ip = '127.0.0.1';

SELECT *
FROM cart
WHERE cart_id = 20 AND cart_ip = '127.0.0.1'
```

Unfortunately, I can't even figure out whether this request is correct or not. I do not see any error messages and no changes occur in the table

I would like to write a query without using stored procedure
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Case *expression* sigh. [this may seem arrogant, but it is the core of your misunderstanding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost right, only case when has to return a value and can not be set there

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `cart` ( cart_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
> , cart_id_product INT(11) NOT NULL
> , cart_price DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
> , cart_count INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
> , cart_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL
> , cart_ip VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
> , PRIMARY KEY (cart_id) USING BTREE ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERt INTO cart VALUEs(20,1,12.1, 3,NOW(),'127.0.0.1')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE cart
> SET cart_count = CASE
>  WHEN cart_count >= 2 THEN cart_count  - 1
>  ELSE 1
>  END
> WHERE cart_id = 20 AND cart_ip = '127.0.0.1';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from cart
> ```
>
> ```
> cart_id | cart_id_product | cart_price | cart_count | cart_datetime       | cart_ip  
> ------: | --------------: | ---------: | ---------: | :------------------ | :--------
>      20 |               1 |      12.10 |          2 | 2020-07-18 21:12:20 | 127.0.0.1
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE cart
> SET cart_count = CASE
>  WHEN cart_count >= 2 THEN cart_count  - 1
>  ELSE 1
>  END
> WHERE cart_id = 20 AND cart_ip = '127.0.0.1';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from cart
> ```
>
> ```
> cart_id | cart_id_product | cart_price | cart_count | cart_datetime       | cart_ip  
> ------: | --------------: | ---------: | ---------: | :------------------ | :--------
>      20 |               1 |      12.10 |          1 | 2020-07-18 21:12:20 | 127.0.0.1
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE cart
> SET cart_count = CASE
>  WHEN cart_count >= 2 THEN cart_count  - 1
>  ELSE 1
>  END
> WHERE cart_id = 20 AND cart_ip = '127.0.0.1';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from cart
> ```
>
> ```
> cart_id | cart_id_product | cart_price | cart_count | cart_datetime       | cart_ip  
> ------: | --------------: | ---------: | ---------: | :------------------ | :--------
>      20 |               1 |      12.10 |          1 | 2020-07-18 21:12:20 | 127.0.0.1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4e466312be53c734c506c7fe0f41914)*

Comment: see now changed example

Comment: `ELSE cart_count = 1` should be just `ELSE 1`

Comment: @AntonínLejsek actually it doesn't matter for that case, i changed it so that nobody gets confused

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `cart` (
 `cart_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cart_id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `cart_price` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `cart_count` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `cart_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `cart_ip` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;`

Comment: also i am using Server version: 5.5.50 MySQL Community Server (GPL) and HeidiSQL as client application

Comment: that doesn't matter at all, change the fiddle to the version you have and it works still

Comment: try to reproduce your error in a fiddle, also post your error,